# Favorites mechanism & common design pattern

Tags: web-app

I'm building a web app which contains many pages. I want to implement a favorites mechanism.

My suggestion is - 
[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21152100/SFP-favorites.jpg]

(1) is the "add to favorites" button (as in google chrome) which opens a small window containing a text box filled with the link, ok & cancel buttons.

(2) is the favorite button on the app toolbox. It opens a panel which allows the user to review & search the favorites, access them, delete and edit.

My question is - Does it make sense to add 2 star icons to the application? Isn't it confusing? Is there a better a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it makes perfect sense. Using a consistent terminology and iconography when designing is key to create a good discoverability and general UX. The user will quickly associate the star icon for representing what they want to keep / not lose, so using the star to represent this feature throughout the application would definitely be the way to go.

Personally I think the way Firefox has it, with a star icon in the URL input to bookmark and then only using a "Bookmarks" label with no reference back to the star icon when browsing your bookmarks is a bit confusing. To me now it feels like the star (which usually conveys "favourite") and the bookmark feature could very well be two separate things. I would have liked to see the association between the bookmark action and the bookmark listing in a more clear way, such as using the established star icon in both occasions for true clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You solution is quite ideal. And like AndroidHustle pointed out, it is not a matter of confusion but a matter of consistency.

Look at the pulse news reader screenshots below.
The first one shows an opened article with the save button on the left menu
The second shows the saved page, when I have no items saved then it explains what it is for which I find to be a good practice, rather than leaving the page blank.

[image]

[image]

Also, once the user is adapt at the application, then he only needs the icons rather than seeing the entire text.